# How to create script to change directory then run

Tags: shell-script, terminal, osx

I am trying to get a script to work that I can run from the desktop or have it load on login. All i want it to do is change do the directory /users/me/sites/sass and then run the command 'npm run compile:sass' thats it. I have tried automator but it throws out an error and wont run, i just tried to save it as an application with a run shell script option and put the above in.

Answer (score 0):

First, get it to work from the command line, so you know everything is working as it should, then focus on running that script from your gui.

Step 1 - create the script

```
echo "cd /users/me/sites/sass ; npm run compile: sass" >> /users/me/myscript
```

Step 2 - make the script executable

```
chmod 775 /users/me/myscript
```

Step 3 - run it and confirm proper operation

```
. /users/me/myscript
```

Step 4 - add a link to the script from your gui

```
(gui dependent, sorry, can't help you here)
```

Comment: In addition, for the "or load on login" ... with the tag of OSx... [SuperUser MacOSx Run Command on Startup Question](https://superuser.com/questions/229773/run-command-on-startup-login-mac-os-x#229792)